# Does a run count if it's made after an unforced out?

Tags: baseball

scenerio: runners on second and third, two outs.  Ball hit to shortstop who immediately tags out the runner going from second to third.  This happens before runner gets to first and before runner from third scores. Would the run count since the last out was not a force but a tag out?

Answer (score 7):

No.

Runs only count if they are plated *before* a tagged 3rd out (and never count on a forced 3rd out).

[MLB rules section 4.09 (a)](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2014/official_baseball_rules.pdf)

> One run shall be scored each time a runner legally advances to and touches first, second, third and home base before three men are put out to end the inning. EXCEPTION: A run is not scored if the runner advances to home base during a play in which the third out is made (1) by the batter-runner before he touches first base; (2) by any runner being forced out; or (3) by a preceding runner who is declared out because he failed to touch one of the bases

In this case, the run is not scored because it does not reach the plate before the third out is recorded (as per the first sentence).